# How to add jBrowser to the frame after the start?

Tags: java, swing, djnativeswing

I have a Starter class, which runs my application:

```
public class Starter {  
    public static Panel createContent() {
          Panel contentPane = new Panel();
          final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
          webBrowser.navigate("http://orientalcraft.org/");
          webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);   
          webBrowser.setStatusBarVisible(false);  
          contentPane.add(webBrowser);
          return contentPane;

      }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        Frame.go();
        NativeInterface.open();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Frame frame = Frame.mainFrame; //mainFrame - instance of Frame
                frame.getContentPane().add(createContent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }

        });

        NativeInterface.runEventPump();   
    }
}
```

And when I trying to add `jBrowser` to the `Frame`, I see nothing about `jBrowser`.. But I can see in a console this:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2293)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2586)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2596)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1318)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUnshared(ObjectInputStream.java:460)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.readMessageFromChannel(OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.java:116)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface$2.run(MessagingInterface.java:392)
```

Please, help me to add a `jBrowser` to existing `jFrame`..

Answer (score 1):

> Please, help me to add a jBrowser to existing jFrame..

When you add (or remove) a component to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The above is for Swing which you question says you are using, but the example code appears to be using a Frame instead of a JFrame. Try using a JFrame. Or for AWT I think you would use `validate()`.

Comment: That's the thing! I need to add jBrowser with all his functions (but when trying to add it as default component it gives much more errors) just like:public Frame(){
            super(Settings.LauncherName);
            
            add(Styles.login);
            add(Styles.pass);
            add(Styles.version);
    }